# How to use the search function?

Tags: support, search

I am looking for a list of all features of the search function. I am including the few I know below.

### Search by tag

Up to five tags can be added to the search query by adding `[tag-name]` at the beginning of the search query. Only posts that contain all tags will show up.

You may also use a wildcard character `*` to mean any amount of characters, so `[tags*]` will give questions with [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), [tags-burniation](/questions/tagged/tags-burniation) or [tags-page](/questions/tagged/tags-page).

### Other search terms

- Use `locked:1` and `locked:0`  for questions that are locked and not
  locked respectievely.
- Use `closed:1` and `closed:0`  for questions that are closed and not closed respectievely.
- `is:Q` and `is:A` will give you questions and answers only
  respectively.

Comment: If you go to `/search`, there is a link on the right - "Advanced Search Tips". Click that to see the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search options are all listed in the [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) help center page.

Additionally, the search page (at `/search`) has an "Advanced Search Tips" link that expands a quick help section with some of the more common options:

> [image]